# How to re-schedule a trigger in Quartz

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz in C# to build a background job. Here is my code:

```
public class BackgroundConfig
{
    private IScheduler scheduler;

    public BackgroundConfig()
    {
        scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();
    }

    public void ScheduleParser()
    {
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ParseJob>()
            .WithIdentity("Parser", "Job")
            .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("ParserTrigger", "Trigger")
            .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(4, 0))
            .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);   
    }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to reschedule that `ParserTrigger` from another class. Here is the code:

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.RescheduleJob()
```

As you can see, there is a function called `RescheduleJob(triggerKey, newTrigger)`, but I don't know how to get the trigger key of `ParserTrigger` from another class. Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From mermory, you can do something like:

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

var trigger = scheduler.GetTrigger("ParserTrigger","Trigger");
scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.JobName, trigger.JobGroup, trigger);
```

(note - untested!)

Comment: sorry, removed "Global" namespace. Again, this is untested, but hopefully will point you in right direction

Comment: Sorry, can you take a look a the `GetTrigger` signature? It only accepts `TriggerKey`, not trigger name and group.

Comment: According to the documentation this was changed in version 2 - http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide.html so have a look at your code and pass in the key instead

Comment: I know that I have to pass in the key, but I don't know how to get the key when I'm in another class, not `BackgroundConfig` class.

Comment: Assuming `BackgroundConfig` has already done the set up, then in your other class, you get get the DefaultScheduler as i shown in my answer, and get the trigger by string, again, as shown

Comment: But the `GetTrigger` function only receive 1 parameter type `TriggerKey`, not string. That makes my problem.